# How can I detect a outside click of mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have mat-form-field component and need to detect a click outside of it. When it opens and I click on any checkbox, it recognize as an outside click and close the dropdown.
I tried to use event.stoppropogation() but it don't work.
How can I prevent onCancelClick() function when I click on the mat option.

```
    <mat-form-field appClickOutside (clickElsewhere)="onCancelClick($event)">
    <mat-select placeholder="Accounts: {{accountsList.length}}" 
    [formControl]="accountsCtrl" [multiple]="true" #multiSelect>
    <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="accountsFilterCtrl">
      <i class="fa fa-close" ngxMatSelectSearchClear></i>
    </ngx-mat-select-search>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts | async" [value]="account" 
    (clickElsewhere)="onCancelClick($event)">
      {{account.name}}
    </mat-option>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 text-right submit-btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    onCancelClick(e: Event) {
     this.accountsCtrl.setValue(this.accountsList);
     this.multiSelect.close();
    }

    ***This is my directive`***
    @Directive({
    selector: '[appClickOutside]'
    })
    export class ClickOutsideDirective {

    @Output() clickElsewhere = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

    constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    public onDocumentClick(event) {
    if (!this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.clickElsewhere.emit(event);
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an ugly workaround which can do the work,

The trick is to check, the mat-focused class exist on the mat-form-field element.

The 'isInputFocused' boolean variable is used to trigger the time we focus on the input

```html
<div #matFormFieldParent>
    <mat-form-field class="input-amount mat-form-field">
```

Then in your component:

```js
import {
  AfterViewChecked,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';


export class YourComponent implements AfterViewChecked {


  @ViewChild('matFormFieldParent') matFormFieldParentElement : ElementRef;
  isInputFocused: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.isInputFocused = false;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.inputFocusProcess(
      this.matFormFieldParentElement
          .nativeElement
          .querySelector('.mat-form-field.mat-focused'));
  }

  private inputFocusProcess(matFormField: ElementRef): void {
    if (matFormField && !this.isInputFocused) {
      this.isInputFocused = true;
    }

    if (!matFormField && this.isInputFocused) {
      this.isInputFocused = false;

      setTimeout(
        () => {
          //
          // Do what you want when you click outside the input
          //
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with css rules. If you inspect your mat-form-field element, you will see that it has no dimensions. Maybe if you give it some properties like min-height: 1px, width: 100%, position: relative it will get dimensions and you will be able to click inside it without it being detected as an outside click.

Answer (score 0):

I use two methods one to track click on the on the element and other to track outside click

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {

  @Output() clickElsewhere = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

  constructor(private eRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) onDocumentClick(event) {
    this.clickElsewhere.emit()
  }

  @HostListener('click',['$event']) onClick(e:MouseEvent) { 
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

}
```

template

```
<div id="control" appClickOutside (clickElsewhere)="showMessage()" >
</div>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6b7t6m)